# Convert to List<dynamic> records gets null

Tags: c#, asp.net

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10CkX.png)I am trying to convert my `List` to `DataTable` but while converting the records count gets 0.

Here is my code:

```
DataAccessProvider dap = new DataAccessProvider(
    Settings.Default.SQLServerConnection, 
    DatabaseType.MSSql);
var employees = dap.SelectAll("Employees").AsEnumerable().ToList();
DataTable Employees = new DataTable();
Employees = ToDataTable(employees);

public DataTable ToDataTable<T>(List<T> items)
{
    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable(typeof(T).Name);
    //Get all the properties
    PropertyInfo[] Props = typeof(T).GetProperties(
        BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
    foreach (PropertyInfo prop in Props)
    {
        //Setting column names as Property names
        dataTable.Columns.Add(prop.Name);
    }
    foreach (T item in items)
    {
        var values = new object[Props.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < Props.Length; i++)
        {
            //inserting property values to datatable rows
            values[i] = Props[i].GetValue(item, null);
        }
        dataTable.Rows.Add(values);
    }
    //put a breakpoint here and check datatable
    return dataTable;
}

public List<dynamic> SelectAll(string tableName)
{
    List<dynamic> result = new List<dynamic>();

    using (IDataReader reader = ExecuteReader("Select * From " + tableName))
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            dynamic expando = new ExpandoObject();
            for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
            {
                string columnName = reader.GetName(i);
                ((IDictionary<String, Object>)expando).Add(
                    columnName, 
                    reader[columnName]);
            }
            result.Add(expando);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

All above are my code. When I debugged I found that in ToDataTable function the Props count gets 0. So what is wrong here?

Comment: You don't have to implement your own `ToDataTable` method because you can use `ToDataTable` extension method but you need to install `MoreLinq` first. Check this answer to know how https://stackoverflow.com/a/42550827/2946329

Comment: @S.Akbari - loks like this question contains its own implementation of a method called `ToDataTable`

Comment: @Jamiec Yes and I guess the OP has been unaware of `ToDataTable` extension method already.

Comment: ExpandoObjects don't have properties like you hope they do. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/32312740/34092

Comment: @S.Akbari right, so your comment/answer on "why is my code not working" is "screw it, use different code"

Comment: I tried with following thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/42550827/2946329 but the result is same and DataTable has no data.
 `DataTable employees = dap.SelectAll("Employees").ToDataTable();`

Comment: @Jamiec Suggesting that someone use an existing library instead of writing their own code to do something is a valid comment, maybe not a good answer, but it's definitely an acceptable comment.

Comment: I tried your code with `T` being a simple class having an `int` and a `string` property. It works fine for me? Did you test with different types for `T`? What exactly happens?

Comment: @RenéVogt its `dynamic`

Comment: ah I see. `dynamic` is just an alias for `object`. `object` does not have public instance properties.

Comment: @Jamiec That's related to weather a question is good or not, not if a comment is.  The whole point of comments is for asking for clarifications or making suggestions that are not valid as answers.

Comment: @RenéVogt See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5523031/dynamic-keyword-vs-object-data-type for object vs dynamic.

Comment: You should try using FastMember where this functionality is already implemented. You can see this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/564366/convert-generic-list-enumerable-to-datatable

Comment: Neither MoreLinq nor FastMember worked for me:(

Comment: I have added my result screenshot

Answer (score 0):

`dynamic` objects do not have *any* properties, let alone public instance ones.

This code outputs zero:

```
dynamic expando = new ExpandoObject();
((IDictionary<String, Object>)expando).Add(
                    "col", 
                   "val");
Console.WriteLine(expando.GetType().GetProperties().Length);
```

(Live example: http://rextester.com/IOTK71323)

If you want to access the dynamic properties, you need to cast it to the same dictionary you do for writing to it, and read the keys/values:

```
dynamic expando = new ExpandoObject();
((IDictionary<String, Object>)expando).Add(
                    "col", 
                   "val");

var dict =  ((IDictionary<String, Object>)expando);
foreach(var kv in dict)
    Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", kv.Key,kv.Value);
```

(Live example: http://rextester.com/RMAW17261)

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `((IDictionary<String, object>)expando).Keys` and passing them in to a new implementation of ToDataTable that uses those keys ('property names').

This is necessary, vs your current Reflection solution, to look up the property names (since as https://stackoverflow.com/a/32312740/34092 states, that won't work).

[Convert dynamic list to datatable c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21672798/convert-dynamic-list-to-datatable-c-sharp/21672842) may be worth a read as well.