# Entity Framework to Datatable

Tags: c#, entity-framework, model-view-controller

Is there any way to convert an Entity Framework query result to a `DataTable`?

or

Is there any way to convert contemporaneity table to `DataTable`? Using C#

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21672867/284240

Comment: What for? For the love of God, tell me why you needed this. DataTable was needed before the advent of ORM. And now EF gives you a filled collection of strongly typed objects, which is much more convenient than DataTable.

Comment: yeah i know still i want to know is there any in built function to do so or not

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use some reflection and generics to build the DataTable.

For example:

```
   public static DataTable CreateDataTable<T>(IEnumerable<T> entities)
    {
        var dt = new DataTable();

        //creating columns
        foreach (var prop in typeof(T).GetProperties())
        {
            dt.Columns.Add(prop.Name, prop.PropertyType);
        }

        //creating rows
        foreach (var entity in entities)
        {
            var values = GetObjectValues(entity);
            dt.Rows.Add(values);
        }


        return dt;
    }

public static object[] GetObjectValues<T>(T entity)
    {
        var values = new List<object>();
        foreach (var prop in typeof(T).GetProperties())
        {
            values.Add(prop.GetValue(entity));
        }

        return values.ToArray();
    }
```